# Invalid submitted Django form data being temporarily used elsewhere in a template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make a view for users to change their usernames and emails. The page works as expected for the most part. However, there is an issue that occurs when a user inputs another user's username. You see, the profile editing page has a heading that displays the current user's username and email. When the user inputs a duplicate username, the heading becomes the invalid username until the page is refreshed. Here is the relevant code:

**View**

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.user, request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated.')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.user, instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context(title='Procfile', u_form=u_form, p_form=p_form))
```

**Form**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "courses/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried making the view return a redirect if the forms aren't valid, but that results in the automatically generated error messages (e.g. A user with that username already exists.) not appearing. Is there a way to prevent the issue while keeping the error messages? My apologies if I'm missing something obvious here. I'm still learning the ins and outs of Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if the values provided are duplicate in the body of the  `if request.method == 'POST':` . You would simply need methods like so in your form class.

```
def clean_email(self):
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username is not unique")

def clean_username(self):
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not unique")
```

You can then make a call to validate the values provided. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115349/how-can-i-checking-username-and-mail-exists-in-django) for an example.